# open full screen UIMoviePlayerController in front of uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

i have an SDK, which prompts the user with an inbox, it's being prompt the following way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewToShow];
```

after entering specific message, it's being prompt the same way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:messageVC.view];
```

the problem is when the message view (which shows uiwebview) has video url, and whenever the video starts and resized to full screen, it's being prompted behind these 2 views, so it's hidden to the user.

my question is, how can i show the video in full screen that way it will be shown properly, infront of these views?

i've tried registering to the `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`notification, and making the following:

```
for (UIView *view in [[self.view superview] subviews]) {
    [view setHidden:YES];
}
```

and for the `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification` notification:

```
for (UIView *view in [[self.view superview] subviews]) {
    [view setHidden:NO];
}
```

it is working, but i'm not sure how good the solution is.....

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, you ever get anywhere? I have found that its an issue with the NavigationController in my situation. By manually creating the NavigationBar and not using a NavigationController, I was able to fix this.

I do not like the solution though as iOS7 has many NavigationController specific behaviors.